# Graph Theory for Dummies Book

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, soft-question, book-recommendation, big-list

Does anyone have a good book on Graph Theory that will introduce me to some of the basic concepts without being so filled with terminology that it's hard to read? I have taken an introductory course (that had no book) and I struggled through it but didn't learn what I should have. I am now a graduate student taking a graduate Graph Theory course (again with no book) and would like a book that can help me develop a stronger base of the beginner topics on my own.

I really would like to stress that the more readable the text is the better it will be for me. Also something with a lot of examples.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Permit me to recommend *Pearls in Graph Theory*:

> Hartsfield, Nora, and Gerhard Ringel. *Pearls in Graph Theory: a Comprehensive Introduction*. Courier Corporation, 2013.
>   ([Dover link](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486432327.html).)

---

[image]

---

Here is an excerpt from an
[enthusiastic review by Joan Hutchinson](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2324291):

> *Pearls in Graph Theory* begins informally and at an elementary level, suitable for
>   a substantial freshman-sophomore course. After intuitive introductions, concepts
>   and theory are developed with increasing depth, leading into material for a good
>   intermediate-level course. Included also are appropriate open conjectures...

Incidentally, it is only \$10-\$20.

Answer (score 4):

There is a free book available online by Diestel, and it's very readable. I used it when I taught an undergraduate course last year. Tons of examples to make the definitions clear:

http://diestel-graph-theory.com/

Comment: Diesel is very readable, but not elementary, covering a significant range of sophisticated modern graph theory in remarkably few pages.

Comment: It looks very nice!

Answer (score 2):

I'm very fond of Trudeau, Dots and Lines. It has been reissued as Introduction To Graph Theory, a much less inviting title.

Answer (score 0):

[Bollobas' "Modern graph theory"](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387984889) is very nice. Would not call it a "for dummies" book, though.

Comment: -1 for mentioning a book which is not what the OP wanted.

Comment: In fact this is exactly the opposite of what OP needs.  IMHO, Bollobas' writing style is mostly aimed at professionals - and he has a tendency to leave holes in his proofs for the reader  to fill in, which is fine but not suitable for beginners.

Comment: @ManuelLafond Chacun a son gout

Comment: @Igor Rivin Of course it might be an easy read for somebody like you :)  But I remember struggling with this book when I was an undergraduate.

Comment: @ManuelLafond Well, my recollection was that it had a very nice selection of topics, and the arguments, complete or no, were quite well chosen...